# Is there any way to use "import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Index;" with Apache lucene 8.6.0

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

I want to use the following code but it's showing an error **Cannot find the symbol** on **Field.Index** and I am using **Apache lucene 8.6.0**

```
 private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String v) throws IOException{
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new Field("",v,Field.Store.YES,Field.Index)); 
        w.addDocument(doc); 
    }
```

So, Is there any way to use Field.Index or any lucene class that can perform this function (*version 8.6.0 is mandatory*)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"this function"_? You can take a look at the [available constructors](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#constructor.summary) for `Field`. There is nothing which matches what you appear to want. One common usage would be `new TextField("title", "War and Peace", Field.Store.YES)`.

Comment: I would recommend you to use 

another type of custom document field types given below  if you dont need to do some custom changes on base field object. 

  [1]: https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/